# Correct or Not? Probability and Geometry

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, density-function

A stick of length  $1$  is broken into two pieces of length  $Y$  and  $1−Y$  respectively, where  $Y$  is uniformly distributed on  $[0,1]$. Let  $R$  be the ratio of the length of the shorter to the length of the longer piece.

Find the PDF  $f_R(r)$  of  $R$.
Hint: What is the PDF of the length of the smaller piece? For  $0<r<1$, 
For $f_R(r)$

I have
$f_R(r)= {2\over(r+1)^2}$ or is the answer $f_R(r)= {1\over(r+1)^2}$

Also, 
$E[R]= ln(4)$ or is the answer, $E[R]= ln(2)−0.5$

Comment: Please read the [help/on-topic] in relation to homework-style questions; we treat them somewhat differently. Please show your work, explaining where your pairs of answers come from. I think both your E(R) values are incorrect.

Comment: See similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33656/119261.

Comment: I have solved the question, I just want someone to confirm me the answer for the same!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**  Here's what I got by simulating the distribution in R.
Your first density function seems to work, but neither of your expectations
seem to be right. [Especially not $\ln(4) > 1;$ a typo maybe?]
With a million iterations, one should expect
about two place accuracy.

```
y = runif(10^6)
v = pmin(y, 1-y);  r = v/pmax(y, 1-y)
mean(r);  sd(r)
[1] 0.3856303
[1] 0.2794012
2*sd(r)/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 0.0005588025    # aprx 95% margin of simulation error

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(v, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 hist(r, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  curve(2/(x+1)^2, add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with the use of simulations and graphs. Maybe you could help me with my solution?

Comment: By simulation, I have shown (to my satisfaction anyhow) that your first proposed density function is correct, but that you have not found the population mean corresponding to that distribution. // If you need help with the derivation, please show your work and maybe someone here can find your mistake evaluating $E(R).$ // If you want someone to do the work for you, this is not exactly the right site,